# CSS: How to set container size equal to background image size

Tags: css

I know how to stretch background image to fit its container (with `background-size` property). But how to achieve the other way around without setting width and height manually?

To better make my point, assume we have a `p` element with one line of text and set its background-image to an picture of 800*600px. How to adjust the width and height of `p` **automatically** to 800*600?

I ask the question because I am looking for a better workflow. It's quite annoying to change width and height in CSS every time I change the image size in Photoshop. The workflow is like below:

1. Change image in Photoshop (likely end up with a slightly different image dimension)
2. Remember that new dimension
3. Go into CSS file looking for that particular element which uses that image as bg
4. Change width and height of the element (if i still remember them correctly..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using a background image, you could use a `img` element and set the containing div's display to `inline-block`. You'd then need to create an inner div to wrap the content and position it absolutely relative to the containing div. Since the `img` is the only thing in the flow, the containing div will resize relative to the image.

Pretty much a hack, but I think it would give the effect you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/Km3Fc/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="yourImg.jpg" />
    <div class="content">
        <!-- Your content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.wrap img + .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a very clean solution

Answer (score 5):

Your only option would be to programatically add the height/width. Compass for Sass has functions that can return the dimensions of the image when the CSS file is compiled: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/image-dimensions/

```
.foo {
    height: image-height('my-img.png');
    width: image-width('my-img.png');
}
```

Comment: Great solution. I will try Compass in my next project

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for CSS3 [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) this should do it:

```
div {
    background-size: contain; /* or cover */
}
```

**EDIT:** using javascript, you could load the image from the background-image property and set the size of the container.

```
(function() {
    var img = new Image();
    var $mydiv = $('#mydiv');
    img.src = $mydiv.css('background-image').slice(4,-1);

    $mydiv.width(img.width).height(img.height);
})();
```

Comment: Oh, i misread your question... You want to set the size of a container according to a background image size... I am not sure how you can do this except if you load the image in javascript.