# Stretch section to height of background image

Tags: css, background-image

I'm using bootstrap, although the example doesn't consider it.

What I need is that the `section` stretches to the height of the background image.

I've built a minimal example, but it doesn't seem to  load background images:

https://codepen.io/lib0/pen/zYxyoLd

Comment: for your info you've put `background-img` rather than `background-image` in the example

Comment: Can you add the `height` property to the background? Or does it need to be fluid?

Comment: Thanks @PatrickMcDermott, it's corrected now.

Comment: It would be better to be fluid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is a different apporach to what you've taken and I've followed this example [CSS: How to set container size equal to background image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961824/css-how-to-set-container-size-equal-to-background-image-size) . It doesn't use the `background-image` property though. I'm not sure if that is a necessity for you.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="https://escolaeducacao.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/dna.jpg" />

    <section class="content">
    to be expanded to the size of the background image.
    </section>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.wrap img + .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Setting the wrap to `position: relative` will cause child elements that are set to `position: absolute` to position itself in relation to that parent element